# Configuring python imports with PyCharm tips

Tags: python, import, flask, structure, pycharm

I had the following project structure in PyCharm:

```
/backend   
  /lib
  /models
  /routes
  /sys
  __init__.py
  config.py
```

then I moved all data from /backend to /backend/app/ and I created next script /backend/run.py

```
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

so now project structure looks like:

```
/backend
  /app
    /lib
    /models
    /routes
    /sys
    __init__.py
    config.py
  run.py
```

after that when i moved all data, I renewed all imports in /backend/app/..., for example:

in backend/app/_ *init* _.py next import:

```
from backend.sys.fbcdb import FbcDb
```

to

```
from app.sys.fbcdb import FbcDb
```

and now my IDE shows unresolved references...

but when i'm running my projects it works fine.
how to resolve all references in PyCharm?

Comment: Have you tried `from  backend.app.sys.fbcdb import FbcDb`?

Comment: my folder /backend dosent contains __init__.py so it not package, and i cant write like this: from backend.app.sys.fbcdb import FbcDb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have **__*init*__**.py at /backend you need to use:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/backend')
```

When you don't have **__*init*__**.py you cannot import the module without adding the path to PYTHONPATH.